# Stripe Checkout integration

Tags: stripe

I see that Stripe can be used with CiviCRM but is Stripe Checkout ( https://stripe.com/checkout) an option with CiviCRM?

Answer (score 9):

Stripe Checkout is not implemented at this time, but I would love to add it in the future.

Source:  I am the maintainer of CiviCRM Stripe integration.

Comment: Are you looking for help (money, code, testing...) to make it happen?

Comment: Yes, definitely!  Development happens on GitHub, and you can see commits from other contributors are graciously accepted:  
https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/commits/4.6-dev

Answer (score 2):

You can not use the checkout option for stripe if you are using it with CiviCRM.

As far as I'm concerned, you can use only direct payment option in     stripe while making payment in CiviCRM.

Please refer a function **doTransferCheckout()** from link:  https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/blob/4.6-dev/CRM/Core/Payment/Stripe.php#L665

it says, 'Use direct billing instead of Transfer method.'

Comment: So Stripe doesn't work as a payment processor?