# Dies CiviCRM support Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe

Does Stripe checkout work with CiviCRM, Drupal combination? Or only Stripe.JS will work with CiviCRM?

Answer (score 1):

You can Follow this discussion to clarify your [Stripe Checkout integration](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7857/stripe-checkout-integration)
which talks about what your question requests